# Rust Cocoa - How to make an NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, rust, nsdictionary

I've been reading around trying to understand it. You can see here `dictionaryWithObjects:objects` the takes an array of Objects and Keys:

```objectivec
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects
                                                       forKeys:keys
                                                         count:count];
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary#overview

---

but `initWithObjectsAndKeys_` only a single Object for input? ‍♂️

```rust
unsafe fn initWithObjectsAndKeys_(self, firstObject: *mut Object) -> *mut Object
```

https://docs.rs/cocoa/0.24.0/cocoa/foundation/trait.NSDictionary.html#tymethod.initWithObjectsAndKeys_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of Rust cocoa APIs are direct wrappers of the underlying Objective-C APIs, like initWithObjectsAndKeys: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1574190-initwithobjectsandkeys?language=objc. Callers are expected to pass a pointer to the first element of a null-terminated array containing alternating value and key elements for the dictionary.

Comment: What happens when your values / "objects", aren't all the same type (`String`) ?
See this dictionary as an example: https://github.com/Joride/Monarch/blob/main/ViewController.swift#L105

Comment: From Josh on GitHub thread: In general, objc types share an underlying representation of the `id` type (eg https://github.com/servo/core-foundation-rs/blob/master/cocoa-foundation/src/foundation.rs#L601) so you would need a vector of `id`s.

Answer (score 1):

Of course after learning how to do it from the great answers here (as well as, before posting this question, searching the repo, all GitHub, and the web for an undisclosed amount of time), I find an example in a test from @Josh Matthews [servo/core-foundation-rs](https://github.com/servo/core-foundation-rs/) library here:

```rust
let mkstr = |s| unsafe { NSString::alloc(nil).init_str(s) };
let keys = vec!["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
let objects = vec!["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

unsafe {
               
  let keys_raw_vec = keys.clone().into_iter().map(&mkstr).collect::<Vec<_>>();
  let objs_raw_vec = objects.clone().into_iter().map(&mkstr).collect::<Vec<_>>();

  let keys_array = NSArray::arrayWithObjects(nil, &keys_raw_vec);
  let objs_array = NSArray::arrayWithObjects(nil, &objs_raw_vec);

  let dict = NSDictionary::dictionaryWithObjects_forKeys_(nil, objs_array, keys_array);
}
```

From https://github.com/servo/core-foundation-rs/blob/355740417e69d3b1a8d909f84d91a6618c9721cc/cocoa-foundation/tests/foundation.rs#L145

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C you call `initWithObjectsAndKeys` like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"Value1", @"Key1",
                                    @"Value2", @"Key2",
                                    @"Value3", @"Key3",
                                    nil, nil
];
```

(Technically speaking, one nil would be sufficient, but I find it lacks symmetry so I put two :-P)

It's a variadic function that can take multiple arguments.

I'm afraid I don't know enough about Rust to know if it can handle things the same way.